# Flutter WebView Crashes on html select

Tags: java, android, flutter, dart

I am trying to import a Website, at the first look, everything is fine, but when I try to open a html dropdown() my app is crashing

I only have this code :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

void main() {
    runApp(new MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
            title: 'Yeet',
                home: Scaffold(
                    body: Container(
                        child: Container(
                            child: WebView(
                                initialUrl: 'https://www.cortexpower.de',
          javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
                                          ),
                                      height: 500,
                                  ),)));
    }
}
```

I've wasted so much time looking for any tips, but I couldn't find a solution.

This is a link to the dropdown

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EkVqr.jpg

Edit:

I created a new Android Device under Android 10 with 4 gb RAM and it is working totally fine

My other device has 1g and Android 5.1

Comment: Please add a screenshot of that dropdown

Comment: You said *all these error* but I cannot see any errrors here. Is it functioning properly in web browser?

Comment: Please check my answer!

Answer (score 3):

After a bit of digging, I found that this issue is being discussed [here](https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview/issues/182) and [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/25767) and not fixed yet,
so I would suggest using [flutter_webview_plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_webview_plugin),
Example

```
 WebviewScaffold(
      url: "https://www.cortexpower.de",
      ),
```

Output

[image]

Comment: This is Plugin isn't good for me, because it isn't in the widget tree, later I want to add some buttons, to call certain controllers, it is not viable with this plugin

Comment: @kmezger did you found a solution for your case (inherited webview)?

Comment: @yuralife at the end I used the [flutter_webview_plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_webview_plugin) you can interact with it just fine